# Android BLE, can not really write characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I'm working on a Android project which is to connect Nexus 7 and a bio sensor through BLE link. The problem is that, I can successfully detect and get list of services and characteristics of the sensor. When I write some data to the specific characteristic, `onCharacteristicWrite` is automatically called and showed me writing operation is successful. However, the sensor never receive anything from the tablet. And if I use similar app on iPhone, everything works fine. So there's no problem with the device. 
Does anyone have any idea of the problem?

Here is my code for write:

```
 private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            mConnected = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            mConnected = false;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

         //Once detected services, write to characteristic for 6 times.
          int count =6;
            while(count>0){

              writeCharacteristic();

                count--;

            }

        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                      BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                      int status){

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){

            Log.d(TAG,"Write to Characteristic Success! !");
        }

    }
};

public boolean writeCharacteristic(){

    //check mBluetoothGatt is available
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return false;
    }

    BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_MY_SERVICE);
    if (Service == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "service not found!");
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = Service
            .getCharacteristic(UUID_MY_CHARACTERISTIC);
    if (characteristic == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "char not found!");
        return false;
    }

    byte[] value = {(byte)300,(byte)100,(byte)100};
    characteristic.setValue(value);

    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

    return status;
}
```

The output shows "Write to Characteristic Success! !" for six times, thus the writing operation succeeded. However, the device shows that nothing been received from tablet. I also tried to write one byte at a time, or add a timer to let the tablet write to sensor every 2 seconds. But none of them worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried turning on HCI snoop (developer settings on the phone) and checking to see what is being sent and being received?

Comment: Hi, I just did. However, I don't know how to open it correctly. Could you tell me how to open it with logcat? I tried open it with text or sublime but turn out to be unreadable. And what is the difference between this log file and the information I get from Android Studio Logcat while I ran the program?

Comment: I believe you need to use Wireshark to read the log. I have not tried it, just figured that it might help you in this case.

Comment: Hi Zomb, thanks for your reply. The problem was solved by manually pairing tablet with device.

Comment: I'm having trouble writing multiple bytes to a characteristic at a time. Does this piece of code work for you?

    byte[] value = {(byte)300,(byte)100,(byte)100};
    characteristic.setValue(value);

    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

Comment: It looks as if createBond was added according to the documentation via SDK 19, are you experiencing any issues with 18 at all with this?

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> Follow Up:
>
> The problem solved by manually pairing the tablet with the device first in the setting instead of pairing by code.
>
> So only using the code snippet of connecting Gatt provided by Android is not good enough to pair the device. I should add another code I found online to pair the devices if I don't want to pair them manually every time:
>
> ```
> private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
>     try {
>         Log.d("pairDevice()", "Start Pairing...");
>         Method m = device.getClass()
>                 .getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
>         m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
>         Log.d("pairDevice()", "Pairing finished.");
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Log.e("pairDevice()", e.getMessage());
>     }
> }
> ```